# Moved my scripts to a external page and they no longer respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a small nav to switch between different stylesheets using jquery, however once I moved my scripts out from the page and into a separate file they no longer respond.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // teal stylsheet
    $("#cssTeal").click(function() {
        $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "stylesheetteal.css"});
    });

    // pink stylesheet
    $("#cssPink").click(function() {
        $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "stylesheetpink.css"});
    });

    // yellow stylesheet
    $("#cssYellow").click(function() {
        $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "stylesheetyellow.css"});
    });

});



<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Mission Statement</title>
<link href="stylesheetteal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" id="teal"/>
<link href="stylesheeetpink.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" id="pink"/>
<link href="stylesheetyellow.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" id="yellow"/>
<link href="scripts.js" rel="external" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="themes">
    <div class="indiv"><a id="cssTeal" href="#teal"><img src="assets/tealcircle.png"></a></div>
    <div class="indiv"><a id="cssPink" href="#pink"><img src="assets/pinkcircle.png"></a></div>
    <div class="indiv"><a id="cssYellow" href="#yellow"><img src="assets/yellowcircle.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the error console say?

Comment: @Mark_M my error console seems to be fine, both pages have are all green

Comment: you should load the file before the `</body>` tag or use event delegation in your script

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i don’t think so. On `document.ready` means that the dom is ready to be queried so it should work. JavaScript files go last because they block the content from loading.

Comment: @muecas , ahh yeah there it is , i over looked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of the loaded scripts and the tag you are using to load your custom scripts. You are using a `link` tag instead of a `script` tag.

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Also add all the script tags just before the closing `</body>` tag. Scripts block content from loading, so you should add them last so they don’t block the rest of the content from being loaded.

Comment: lol you posted it already :D, didnt saw it, i will delete my answer

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam ;-) haha quicky fingers.

Comment: :D haha i got puzzled with the event delegation and didnt noticed the `document.ready` :D , will vote up too , cheers